# SwiftのMapKitで地図をドラッグして移動する方法

Tags: swift, mapkit

タイトルの通りiPhoneなどの標準のMapアプリなどで行える地図をドラッグして表示範囲を移動する処理を実装したいです.

なにか参考になるようなコードのリンクや公式のAPIドキュメントなどがあれば教えていただけると幸いです.

Answer (score 2):

どのように作っているかわかりませんが、
storyboardの場合、
1) 普通にプロジェクトを作成し、viewにMKMapViewを配置。
2) constraintsをつけ、viewcontrollerに@IBOutletでmapViewをつなげる。
3) import MapKitを記述

この3つだけで、ドラッグ、指二本による拡大・縮小、回転など基本動作は全部できますよ？